# How do you get the armour plates off in the Spine of Deathwing encounter?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the new Spine of Deathwing fight, to get the armour plates off you have to kill the tendons.  Does this have to be done in one go or can you do it in two attempts? Does their health reset each time they manage to seal a plate back on?

Comment: And does it matter what side the add blows up to what side is revealed?

Answer (score 4):

To get the armor plates off Deathwing you have to first kill a tentacle or corruption which summons a hideous amalgamation, tank this new mob next to the plate and then after it absorbs nine corrupted bloods kill it. This will cause a nuclear explosion that will lift an armor plate partially. When the plate lifts it will expose the burning tendons. Have everyone focus all damage on these tendons and the plate will be removed. If the plate gets sealed on the tendons health will not reset but the next amalgamation has to be blown up on the same side. Then just rinse and repeat for all the plates. If you are sucessful you will be ready to face the  [Madness of Deathwing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9V1PB2tnoY) Good Luck!

Comment: Have recently killed it the tendon health doesn't reset as long as you blow it up on same side as the tendon you just nuked so if you blow it up on the right hand side the right tendon is revealed if you don't kill it first time you blow it up on the right again its health doesn't reset (And madness was easier than spine lol)

Comment: I do agree that the Madness was easier, and the spine seemed like filler space, and lacks epicness.